# Regex to exclude values between braces and apply pattern on the rest

Tags: regex, oracle, regex-negation

I had the following values in a field

```
Aa11
BBB-
BBB+
A- /*-
A3
Ca
```

I would use the regex

```
(([A-Z](([abc]+\d?)|\d))|([A-Z]+[+-]?)
```

which worked fine. however, now I have another new set of data

```
(p)A3
(q)A- /*-
```

How do I make sure I ignore the brackets and values between them to apply my above regex?

I am doing this using REGEX_SUBSTR in oracle.

Comment: Your regex is invalid. Please post the working one, and explain what exact problem is. What do you need to get in the end given the above input?

Comment: You could try catching parens with: `(\([^)]*\))?` and ignoring this subgroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression `\(.*?\)` will match opening and closing brackets with as few characters as possible between them and `[^(]*?` will match zero-or-as-few-as-possible non-open bracket characters. You can combine these to give the regular expression `^([^(]*?\(.*?\))*?[^(]*?` which will match as few as possible bracket groups (provided you do not have nested brackets) until your required pattern is found.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcb6c/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'Aa11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBB-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBB+' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A- /*-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ca' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '(p)A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '(q)A- /*-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '(Ca)Cb(Cc)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '--(Ca)--(Cb)--Cc(--Ca)' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^([^(]*?\(.*?\))*?[^(]*?([A-Z]([abc]+\d?|\d|[A-Z]*[+-]?))',
         1,    -- Start at 1st character
         1,    -- Find the 1st occurrence
         NULL, -- No flags
         2     -- Return 2nd capturing group
       ) AS regex_output
FROM   data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcb6c/2/0)**:

```
|                  VALUE | REGEX_OUTPUT |
|------------------------|--------------|
|                   Aa11 |          Aa1 |
|                   BBB- |         BBB- |
|                   BBB+ |         BBB+ |
|                 A- /*- |           A- |
|                     A3 |           A3 |
|                     Ca |           Ca |
|                  (p)A3 |           A3 |
|              (q)A- /*- |           A- |
|             (Ca)Cb(Cc) |           Cb |
| --(Ca)--(Cb)--Cc(--Ca) |           Cc |
```

Comment: thanks, thats pretty much what I needed. I am still understanding the workings of this solution though. I had broken down it into two steps to remove anything with braces and then apply the older regex to extract the value